# IOS swift sql query return only 1 digit of number

Tags: ios, sql, sql-server, swift

reacently started using swift and i have a problem creating some code. I was using this https://github.com/martinrybak/SQLClient project to connect my ios to mssql. I am doing so far, but i realized using this method i got only one digit of integer number from sql server. Is it something with my swift code i do wrong?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            let client = SQLClient.sharedInstance()


            client?.connect(Constants.serwerAdress, username: Constants.userName, password: Constants.password, database: Constants.databaseName) {
                success in

                if success {
                    client?.execute("select A FROM B") {
                        results in

                        for table in results as AnyObject! as! NSArray {
                            for row in table as AnyObject! as! NSArray {

                                for column in row as! NSDictionary {

                                    print("\(column.key) = \(column.value)")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        client?.disconnect()
                        DoSomethingElse()
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: @Whencesover what is A?

Comment: @TusharSharma just an IntegerCOlumn from database. values are 1,10,20. And i got back 1,1,2 from column.value